# Is is necessary to use security plugin for wordpress?

Tags: security

There are many WordPress security plugins like limit login attempts, Wordfence Security.

Is is necessary to use this type of security plugin for WordPress?

Comment: The short answer is _no_. The long answer: _It depends on your skills to make a site secure and monitor it._

Answer (score 2):

This highly depends on your capabilities as a developer and you are addressing multiple questions in one go:

- Your servers need to be secured, might benefit from DDos mitigation systems like a CDN or like large hosters offer (AWS, GCE, etc.)
- Your user(s) input, both frontend and backend, should be validated, sanitized and escaped before going into the DB
- …

If you have no idea of basic security measurements, then it might be a good idea to enable such a plugin from time to time—do not leave such a plugin active, if it does not monitor every single user activity and DB change, which will be a stupid idea performance wise. Still better would be to get a sysadmin to care about your servers and really good developers to review your applications code.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no such need. Just add simple captcha solving plugin so that you can safe your website from brute force attack.

But if you find something weird then you must contact some expert whom can find security issues in your website